# Cannot create a SVN repository in XCode

Tags: xcode, svn, version-control

I created a project in XCode and tried to add it to SVN. I went to File -> Source Control -> Repository. In the Add a Repository dialog box, I enter the URL as below:

Name: test
Location: http://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:8080
Type: Subversion

After I clicked Add, the IDE seemed to be executing something and kept showing me the progress bar. And I didn't get any error message.

Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure that your problem is linked to XCode? Are you able to create SVN repositories from the [command line](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-repositories_organizer/SettingupaSubversionRepositoryfromtheCommandLine/SettingupaSubversionRepositoryfromtheCommandLine.html) for example?

Comment: I tried the local repository using command line and the connection was successful, but not within xcode. btw, I'm using xcode 4.